# How to set only vertical padding?

Tags: html, css, padding

Sometimes I would like to set top and bottom padding explicitly on an element but leave left and right padding to the unchanged browser default. I know I can write

```
.myElement { padding-top: 20px; }
.myElement { padding-bottom: 20px; }
```

but this way I need to repeat both the selector `.myElement` and the length value twice - or rather copy and paste the whole line and switch left with right.
I was hoping to find something less redundant, so I tried to use `padding` with two values and replace the second length with `inherit`. That's not good CSS, I know, it was an attempt, but it doesn't work either (sets horizontal padding to 0):

```
.myElement { padding: 20px inherit; }
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/185ty3yp/

Any advice how to do it better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand what you want : **you're looking for a way to only assign vertical padding with `padding` property (and keep original horizontal padding if it's set)**.

So you already have the answer :

```
.myElement { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;  }
```

**You can't do that only with `padding` property**, or you'll need to set horizontal value.

Or, you can consider using **CSS preprocessors** (such as Sass or Less), it will surely helps you to achieve this.

Comment: It seems to me that you are the only person who actually read the entire question.

Comment: As I see the other answer, I can only agree with you.

Answer (score 12):

These days you can do it like this:

```css
.myElement { padding-block: 20px; }
```

[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_padding-block)

Answer (score 11):

you can use `padding-block` property to set vertical padding and padding-inline to set horizontal padding.

```
padding-block: 20px; /*vertical padding */
padding-inline: 20px; /*horizontal padding*/
```

The same goes for margin, use `margin-block` to set vertical margin and margin-inline to set horizontal margin.

`margin-inline: auto;` can be used to center a div.

Answer (score 1):

I understand one of the reasons for finding vertical padding might be wanting just to change one place in future modification.  If so, we can try:

```
.element{
    --title-vertical-padding: 20px;
    padding-top: var(--title-vertical-padding);
    padding-bottom: var(--title-vertical-padding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ul1, #ul2{
  padding:20px 0; /* top and bottom 20px, left and right 0 */
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

you can only set padding to either a fixed length or a percent, no other values I'm afraid

Answer (score -1):

try this code  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/185ty3yp/3/)

```
#ul1, #ul2 {
    background-color: cyan;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#ul2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
padding: 20px 50px 75px 100px;

//top padding is 20px
//right padding is 50px
//bottom padding is 75px
//left padding is 100px
```

In your case you can apply like this if it is common for any ul

```
ul
{
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

any specific places you can override this css.

check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/185ty3yp/5/)